# Сборка react проекта через create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel

Я начинающий react разработчик.
Нужна помощь со сборкой проекта, сделанного через create-react-app.
При разработке через команду npm start все работает отлично, но после npm build созданные файлы, включая index.html выдают ошибки в консоле. При этом serve -s build прекрасно работает.
В интернете нашел много статей на счет webpack и babel. Но как новичку достаточно сложно в них разобраться. Хотелось бы получить просто main.js и main.css, которые потом можно применить к любому index.html c элементом содержащим корневой тег.
Что можете посоветовать? Может годные и актуальные статьи или готовый конфиг.

Comment: Лучше расскажите, как вы пытаетесь запустить билд, просто заходите в папку public и открывает index.html в браузере? И что за ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Да, через index.html. Пробовал еще кешированные файлы js и css положить в проект бэка - laravel и загрузить в индексный файл там. Тоже пустая страница. Я думаю, что неправильно понимаю алгоритм билдинга. 
Но хотелось бы получить независимые файлы или хотя бы понять, что происходит сейчас. 
Неужели придется запускать проект на сервере через serve -s build. Как тогда там быть с картинками и зависимостями?

Comment: Ну смотрите, собранные файлы после билда появляются в папке build, которые и нужно запускать и брать оттуда. По идее чистое приложение будет спокойно запускаться оттуда. Перенос содержимого build на сервер тоже не должен вызывать ошибок. Поэтому и интересуют ошибки так же. Можно еще почитать начальные статьи вроде этой: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-react-project-with-create-react-app-ru Ну и да, желательно иметь сервер, поскольку некоторые операции могут быть заблокированы браузером после запуска не через сервер.